# PostgreSQL: varchar(1) and Umlaut

Tags: postgresql

I have a `VARCHAR(1)` field in postgresql.
Now I export data from a postgresql 9.4 server with `pg_dump`
and import it to a postgresql 9.5 server with pgsql.

When I import it, I get an error:

> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(1) COPY XXX "Ö"

That means in the table there is the value `"Ö"` which takes 2 bytes instead of 1 byte.

- Must I increase the column to `VARCHAR(2)`?
- Is there another way to keep `VARCHAR(1)` and use a locale etc.?
- Why could this data ever be stored there?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix:

The encoding of the target database was wrong and had to be set to UTF8.

Comment: Right, so PostgreSQL interpreted the byte sequence as several single byte characters rather than one multi-byte character.